# Trying to read StdClass Object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I decoded a JSON array which contained keys and values in PHP. The JSON looks like this *(shortened for easier understanding)*:

```
[{"code":"123"},{"identification":"Some item"},{"price":"$20"}]
```

After I `json_decode`'d it, it looked like this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 123 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [identification] => Some item ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [price] => $20 ) )
```

How can I read both the key and the value?

I already tried searching on SO all over and already tried something like this:

```
foreach ($jarray as $key) {
    echo 0->$key;
}
```

which throws an 500 (ISE) error.

Also tried this:

```
foreach ($jarray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
    echo $value;
}
```

which also throws an 500 error.

I don't know how to accomplish this...

**EDIT:** Basically, I just want to iterate trough the whole thing and get key and value every time, like this:

```
code - 123
identification - Some item
price - $20
...
```

Comment: add `true` as the second parameter to your `json_decode()` call

Comment: `$key` is an array/object, so you can't just echo it out. If you'd have looked at your logs, you would have seen "array to string conversion" or "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: Yes, that json string says that you have an array `[]` of objects. `$jarray[0]` has one key of `code` with the value `"123"` .. `$jarray[0]->code; // 123`

Comment: using `var_dump()` is a bit more lenient than trying to `echo` things out, for future reference.

Comment: @Blake I tried to do `$jarray[0]` and it returned `array(1) { ["code"]=> string(3) "123" }`, but now how do I get the string "code", without specifying it? I tried `$jarray[0][0]`, but that returns `NULL`... Basically, I just want to iterate trough the whole thing and get key + value every time.

Comment: @Blake Thanks for the `var_dump()`, I didn't knew exactly what it does, now after a bit googling it, I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json = '[{"code":"123"},{"identification":"Some item"},{"price":"$20"}]';
$jarray = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($jarray as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
        echo $key;
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Works perfect. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @bassxzero This code would have worked fine without converting to an array instead of an object on the `json_decode()`

Comment: @bassxzero Thanks you too :)

Comment: @Fusseldieb Blake brought to my attention that this code would worked fine, so it looks like i was just being a needy little bitch. Thanks for the "Thanks" though lol

Answer (score 0):

```
I hope so it will reduce loop process confusion and simple to do this task. 


$text = '[{"code":"123"},{"identification":"Some item"},{"price":"$20"}]';
$array = json_decode($text);**strong text**
foreach($array as $value)
{
    $array = (array)$value;
    $x = each($array);
    echo $x['key'];
    echo "====>>>>";
    echo $x['value'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: How is your answer better than the accepted answer above?